# WUBI - No root system file defined

Tags: wubi

I've been trying to install ubuntu 11.04 on Asus k50IJ notebook. All via Wubi went without problem. After a reboot, everything starts but during veryfying the installation, this error appears:

> "No root system file defined"

I tried to run `chkdsk` because I thought there might be some HDD problems, yet nothing has been found.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/384056/how-can-i-run-a-shell-command-in-windows-without-the-shell-closing-itself-automa/384059#384059) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/99112/wubis-root-disk-is-missing-but-you-can-still-log-in-as-a-guest-where-is-the), it must solve it.

Comment: Duh, ran chkdsk /r - same stuff happens. I've localized my root.disc file. Ubuntu installer runs up, it just notifies me the error mentioned before during installation.

Comment: Then you should wait for someone to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When this happens on a Wubi installation, it is is generally due to:

1. Minor partition table errors
2. A MBR partition table but some leftover GPT partition table data
3. Unsupported raid

Probably the best way to diagnose would be to boot an Ubuntu CD as a live CD (select `Try Ubuntu` without installing) and run the [bootinfoscript](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/).

You can also just hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> when you get that error to drop to a terminal and run:
`sudo parted -l` and `sudo fdisk -l`
The first will tell you if there are partition table errors. The second will tell you if there is some leftover GPT data (usually if you reuse a disk from a Mac). If you need to remove this GPT data you can use `fixparts` found [here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/).

For example, this `sudo fdisk -l` output shows that a *GUID partition table is detected, but does not seem to be used*:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition Boot Start Sector End Sector # of Sectors Id System

/dev/sda1 * 2,048 206,847 204,800 7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda2 206,848 307,202,047 306,995,200 7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3 307,202,048 976,771,071 669,569,024 f W95 Extended (LBA)
/dev/sda5 307,204,096 614,404,095 307,200,000 7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda6 614,406,144 976,771,071 362,364,928 7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS


GUID Partition Table detected, but does not seem to be used.
```

Running `sudo blkid` may provide information regarding any fakeraid partitions (there are probably better tools for checking the raid setup but I'm not familiar with these).