# Error after installing Ubuntu 12.04 using Wubi

Tags: 12.04, installation, partitioning, wubi, filesystem

After using Windows Ubuntu Installer from within Windows, I am prompted to restart, so I follow the directions. When I try to start Ubuntu after restarting, the desktop background appears, but then a loading bar with this title appears.

> Verifying the installation configuration...

While this is loading, [an error window pops up that says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9V1w2.jpg)

> No root file system is defined
>
> Please correct this from the partitioning menu

There is only an 'Ok' button available to click, and if I click that the same error window appears. I do not know how to get to the "partitioning menu" from this state, so the only option I have is to shut down my computer.

What can I do so that Ubuntu finds a "root file system"? Can I diagnose this problem via Windows? Does anyone have any insight?

FYI - I am using a new ultrabook with 6GB RAM, Intel i7 3rd gen processor, and no CD/DVD drive.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/103495/14916

Comment: possible duplicate of [WUBI - No root system file defined](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103345/wubi-no-root-system-file-defined)

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling Ubuntu from within Windows. Then, re-download the Wubi installer and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried, but got the same result :(