# Dual Boot installation error "no root file system is defined" for 12.04 LTS

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, wubi

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 using WUBI.exe from within windows 7. All goes well but when it restarts and installation proceeds it gives and error "No root file system defined".
I have tried booting from live USB and Live CD but the same error occurs. Then i downloaded 11.10 version and booted into it using live USB but same error occurs there.

Now the thing is that i have 4 partitions on hard disk:

1- C: 147GB (with WINDOWS 7 installed)

2- D, E which i use for file storage in windows

3- G: 19GB NTFS formatted from windows

I am trying to install Ubuntu into this G drive. I want to keep my windows 7 files and installation intact.
I have tried it a while ago for 11.10 and at that time it all went super smooth. I have tried rebuilding the partition table from cmd.exe in windows and i have also tried by formatting my G drive to ext3 using Easeus Partition manager in windows and then installing using wubi but wubi.exe didn't detected the partition formatted to ext3.
When i ran the installation wizard from within ubuntu running through live usb, i got a window with `DEVICE= /dev/sda` and no type no size nothing.

Here when i choose my 320GB drive it just gives the option as in picture and when i pressed install the same error "no root file system defined".
I have tried to select the new partition table option but it give me the window to create a partition by dividing 320GB whole into whatever i want. I don't proceed into that option because i think i will ruin my windows 7 stuff.

I am posting the pictures at of installation steps i have defined in the following link please have a look.

[image]
[image]

Please help me!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/135705/no-root-file-system-is-defined-error-during-installation

Comment: possible duplicate of [WUBI - No root system file defined](http://askubuntu.com/questions/103345/wubi-no-root-system-file-defined)